# How to download file without save as option using XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

How can I download my file without having the following popup show up?
I want the file to save discretely in a specified folder (a folder of my choosing).

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1fQH.png)

```
var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AkifManzoor124/Testing/master/package.json";

var filename = newDownload.substring(newDownload.lastIndexOf("/") + 1).split("?")[0];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response); // xhr.response is a blob
    a.download = filename; // Set the file name.
    a.click();
};
xhr.open('GET', newDownload);
xhr.send();
```

What I am trying to do is a test on how to download a file and later on be able to download zip files which will be used to update an app.

Comment: If the file will be on your server is can possible to get the content of json, but its will be download to temp dir, not a specific path.

However, another server that is not under your control can not perform any ajax requests because there is a browser-level blocking for security reasons.
To enable this, the server to which the request is sent must return headers called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

For more information, 
[please see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: I think your code is correct. Your issue is a browser setting I believe. For instance in Chrome settings I have a checkbox labeled "Ask where to save each file before downloading".  Your browser probably has a similar setting. You won't be able to override this setting for your end-users via javascript.

Comment: You will ALWAYS have the pop up asking where to save the file, as javaScript has no access to the file system. Otherwise any server could randomly decide to put files in your filesystem, that is why the user needs to agree on downloading and the location of the download.

The issue is that the client ALWAYS has to choose where to place the file, if you are the client then why not try wget or python requests (to suggest some really simple ones but there are more options), or if you really want it to be javaScript (this is an overkill) a nodejs app that downloads to the place you want.